# Video Compression Using Sili Compressor in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, compression, video-compression

```
var des="/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/"
var newpath= SiliCompressor.with(this).compressVideo(filepath,"newmovies")
```

I'm compressing a video of 14 mb and it reduces to just 324kb. Video compression using sili compressor in Android kotlin reduces video quality too much.

If I do compression with custom resolution:

```
var newpath= SiliCompressor.with(this).compressVideo(filepath,"newmovies",1080,1920,30)
```

it decreases video quality too much.
How can I compress a video in android other than through FFMEG?

I have try media codec but it didn't work.

[here is the image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqlhU.png)

```
 public String compressVideo(String videoFilePath, String destinationDir, int outWidth, int outHeight, int bitrate) throws URISyntaxException {
        boolean isconverted = MediaController.getInstance(mContext).convertVideo(videoFilePath, new File(destinationDir), outWidth, outHeight, bitrate);
        if (isconverted) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Video Conversion Complete");
        } else {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Video conversion in progress");
        }

        return MediaController.cachedFile.getPath();

    }

 private boolean convertVideo(Context context, Uri videoContentUri, final String sourcePath, File destDir, int outWidth, int outHeight, int outBitrate) {
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

        if (sourcePath != null) {
            this.path = sourcePath;
            retriever.setDataSource(path);
        } else if (context != null && videoContentUri != null) {
            retriever.setDataSource(context, videoContentUri);
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        String width = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
        String height = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
        String rotation = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION);

        long startTime = -1;
        long endTime = -1;

        int resultWidth = outWidth > 0 ? outWidth : DEFAULT_VIDEO_WIDTH;
        int resultHeight = outHeight > 0 ? outHeight : DEFAULT_VIDEO_HEIGHT;

        int rotationValue = Integer.valueOf(rotation);
        int originalWidth = Integer.valueOf(width);
        int originalHeight = Integer.valueOf(height);

        int bitrate = outBitrate > 0 ? outBitrate : DEFAULT_VIDEO_BITRATE;
        int rotateRender = 0;

        File cacheFile = null;
        try {
            cacheFile = new File(getCompressedVideoPath(destDir));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18 && resultHeight > resultWidth && resultWidth != originalWidth && resultHeight != originalHeight) {
            int temp = resultHeight;
            resultHeight = resultWidth;
            resultWidth = temp;
            rotationValue = 90;
            rotateRender = 270;
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20) {
            if (rotationValue == 90) {
                int temp = resultHeight;
                resultHeight = resultWidth;
                resultWidth = temp;
                rotationValue = 0;
                rotateRender = 270;
            } else if (rotationValue == 180) {
                rotateRender = 180;
                rotationValue = 0;
            } else if (rotationValue == 270) {
                int temp = resultHeight;
                resultHeight = resultWidth;
                resultWidth = temp;
                rotationValue = 0;
                rotateRender = 90;
            }
        }

        //ParcelFileDescriptor descriptor = null; //"w" specify's write mode
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;
        try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor descriptor = null;
            if (sourcePath != null) {
                descriptor = mContext.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(Uri.fromFile(new File(sourcePath)), "r");
            } else {
                descriptor = mContext.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(videoContentUri, "r");
            }
            fileDescriptor = descriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }


        videoConvertFirstWrite = true;
        boolean error = false;
        long videoStartTime = startTime;

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (resultWidth != 0 && resultHeight != 0) {
            MP4Builder mediaMuxer = null;
            MediaExtractor extractor = null;

            try {
                MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                Mp4Movie movie = new Mp4Movie();
                movie.setCacheFile(cacheFile);
                movie.setRotation(rotationValue);
                movie.setSize(resultWidth, resultHeight);
                mediaMuxer = new MP4Builder().createMovie(movie);
                extractor = new MediaExtractor();

                if (sourcePath != null && fileDescriptor != null) {
                    extractor.setDataSource(fileDescriptor);
                } else if (context != null && videoContentUri != null) {
                    extractor.setDataSource(context, videoContentUri, null);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }


                int videoIndex;
                videoIndex = selectTrack(extractor, false);

                if (videoIndex >= 0) {
                    MediaCodec decoder = null;
                    MediaCodec encoder = null;
                    InputSurface inputSurface = null;
                    OutputSurface outputSurface = null;

                    try {
                        long videoTime = -1;
                        boolean outputDone = false;
                        boolean inputDone = false;
                        boolean decoderDone = false;
                        int swapUV = 0;
                        int videoTrackIndex = -5;

                        int colorFormat;
                        int processorType = PROCESSOR_TYPE_OTHER;
                        String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER.toLowerCase();
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
                            MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = selectCodec(MIME_TYPE);
                            colorFormat = selectColorFormat(codecInfo, MIME_TYPE);
                            if (colorFormat == 0) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("no supported color format");
                            }
                            String codecName = codecInfo.getName();
                            if (codecName.contains("OMX.qcom.")) {
                                processorType = PROCESSOR_TYPE_QCOM;
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 16) {
                                    if (manufacturer.equals("lge") || manufacturer.equals("nokia")) {
                                        swapUV = 1;
                                    }
                                }
                            } else if (codecName.contains("OMX.Intel.")) {
                                processorType = PROCESSOR_TYPE_INTEL;
                            } else if (codecName.equals("OMX.MTK.VIDEO.ENCODER.AVC")) {
                                processorType = PROCESSOR_TYPE_MTK;
                            } else if (codecName.equals("OMX.SEC.AVC.Encoder")) {
                                processorType = PROCESSOR_TYPE_SEC;
                                swapUV = 1;
                            } else if (codecName.equals("OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.H264E")) {
                                processorType = PROCESSOR_TYPE_TI;
                            }
                            Log.e("tmessages", "codec = " + codecInfo.getName() + " manufacturer = " + manufacturer + "device = " + Build.MODEL);
                        } else {
                            colorFormat = MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface;
                        }
                        Log.e("tmessages", "colorFormat = " + colorFormat);

                        int resultHeightAligned = resultHeight;
                        int padding = 0;
                        int bufferSize = resultWidth * resultHeight * 3 / 2;
                        if (processorType == PROCESSOR_TYPE_OTHER) {
                            if (resultHeight % 16 != 0) {
                                resultHeightAligned += (16 - (resultHeight % 16));
                                padding = resultWidth * (resultHeightAligned - resultHeight);
                                bufferSize += padding * 5 / 4;
                            }
                        } else if (processorType == PROCESSOR_TYPE_QCOM) {
                            if (!manufacturer.toLowerCase().equals("lge")) {
                                int uvoffset = (resultWidth * resultHeight + 2047) & ~2047;
                                padding = uvoffset - (resultWidth * resultHeight);
                                bufferSize += padding;
                            }
                        } else if (processorType == PROCESSOR_TYPE_TI) {
                            //resultHeightAligned = 368;
                            //bufferSize = resultWidth * resultHeightAligned * 3 / 2;
                            //resultHeightAligned += (16 - (resultHeight % 16));
                            //padding = resultWidth * (resultHeightAligned - resultHeight);
                            //bufferSize += padding * 5 / 4;
                        } else if (processorType == PROCESSOR_TYPE_MTK) {
                            if (manufacturer.equals("baidu")) {
                                resultHeightAligned += (16 - (resultHeight % 16));
                                padding = resultWidth * (resultHeightAligned - resultHeight);
                                bufferSize += padding * 5 / 4;
                            }
                        }

                        extractor.selectTrack(videoIndex);
                        if (startTime > 0) {
                            extractor.seekTo(startTime, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_PREVIOUS_SYNC);
                        } else {
                            extractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_PREVIOUS_SYNC);
                        }
                        MediaFormat inputFormat = extractor.getTrackFormat(videoIndex);

                        MediaFormat outputFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, resultWidth, resultHeight);
                        outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, colorFormat);
                        outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitrate != 0 ? bitrate : 921600);
                        outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 25);
                        outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 10);
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
                            outputFormat.setInteger("stride", resultWidth + 32);
                            outputFormat.setInteger("slice-height", resultHeight);
                        }

                        encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
                        encoder.configure(outputFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
                            inputSurface = new InputSurface(encoder.createInputSurface());
                            inputSurface.makeCurrent();
                        }
                        encoder.start();

                        decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(inputFormat.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME));
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
                            outputSurface = new OutputSurface();
                        } else {
                            outputSurface = new OutputSurface(resultWidth, resultHeight, rotateRender);
                        }
                        decoder.configure(inputFormat, outputSurface.getSurface(), null, 0);
                        decoder.start();

                        final int TIMEOUT_USEC = 2500;
                        ByteBuffer[] decoderInputBuffers = null;
                        ByteBuffer[] encoderOutputBuffers = null;
                        ByteBuffer[] encoderInputBuffers = null;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                            decoderInputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
                            encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
                                encoderInputBuffers = encoder.getInputBuffers();
                            }
                        }

                        while (!outputDone) {
                            if (!inputDone) {
                                boolean eof = false;
                                int index = extractor.getSampleTrackIndex();
                                if (index == videoIndex) {
                                    int inputBufIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
                                    if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                                        ByteBuffer inputBuf;
                                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                                            inputBuf = decoderInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];
                                        } else {
                                            inputBuf = decoder.getInputBuffer(inputBufIndex);
                                        }
                                        int chunkSize = extractor.readSampleData(inputBuf, 0);
                                        if (chunkSize < 0) {
                                            decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, 0, 0L, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                                            inputDone = true;
                                        } else {
                                            decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, chunkSize, extractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
                                            extractor.advance();
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else if (index == -1) {
                                    eof = true;
                                }
                                if (eof) {
                                    int inputBufIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
                                    if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                                        decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, 0, 0L, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                                        inputDone = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            boolean decoderOutputAvailable = !decoderDone;
                            boolean encoderOutputAvailable = true;
                            while (decoderOutputAvailable || encoderOutputAvailable) {
                                int encoderStatus = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_USEC);
                                if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                                    encoderOutputAvailable = false;
                                } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                                        encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
                                    }
                                } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                                    MediaFormat newFormat = encoder.getOutputFormat();
                                    if (videoTrackIndex == -5) {
                                        videoTrackIndex = mediaMuxer.addTrack(newFormat, false);
                                    }
                                } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
                                    throw new RuntimeException("unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + encoderStatus);
                                } else {
                                    ByteBuffer encodedData;
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                                        encodedData = encoderOutputBuffers[encoderStatus];
                                    } else {
                                        encodedData = encoder.getOutputBuffer(encoderStatus);
                                    }
                                    if (encodedData == null) {
                                        throw new RuntimeException("encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus + " was null");
                                    }
                                    if (info.size > 1) {
                                        if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) == 0) {
                                            if (mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(videoTrackIndex, encodedData, info, false)) {
                                                didWriteData(false, false);
                                            }
                                        } else if (videoTrackIndex == -5) {
                                            byte[] csd = new byte[info.size];
                                            encodedData.limit(info.offset + info.size);
                                            encodedData.position(info.offset);
                                            encodedData.get(csd);
                                            ByteBuffer sps = null;
                                            ByteBuffer pps = null;
                                            for (int a = info.size - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
                                                if (a > 3) {
                                                    if (csd[a] == 1 && csd[a - 1] == 0 && csd[a - 2] == 0 && csd[a - 3] == 0) {
                                                        sps = ByteBuffer.allocate(a - 3);
                                                        pps = ByteBuffer.allocate(info.size - (a - 3));
                                                        sps.put(csd, 0, a - 3).position(0);
                                                        pps.put(csd, a - 3, info.size - (a - 3)).position(0);
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }

                                            MediaFormat newFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, resultWidth, resultHeight);
                                            if (sps != null && pps != null) {
                                                newFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-0", sps);
                                                newFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-1", pps);
                                            }
                                            videoTrackIndex = mediaMuxer.addTrack(newFormat, false);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    outputDone = (info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0;
                                    encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);
                                }
                                if (encoderStatus != MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                                    continue;
                                }

                                if (!decoderDone) {
                                    int decoderStatus = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_USEC);
                                    if (decoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                                        decoderOutputAvailable = false;
                                    } else if (decoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {

                                    } else if (decoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                                        MediaFormat newFormat = decoder.getOutputFormat();
                                        Log.e("tmessages", "newFormat = " + newFormat);
                                    } else if (decoderStatus < 0) {
                                        throw new RuntimeException("unexpected result from decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + decoderStatus);
                                    } else {
                                        boolean doRender;
                                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
                                            doRender = info.size != 0;
                                        } else {
                                            doRender = info.size != 0 || info.presentationTimeUs != 0;
                                        }
                                        if (endTime > 0 && info.presentationTimeUs >= endTime) {
                                            inputDone = true;
                                            decoderDone = true;
                                            doRender = false;
                                            info.flags |= MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM;
                                        }
                                        if (startTime > 0 && videoTime == -1) {
                                            if (info.presentationTimeUs < startTime) {
                                                doRender = false;
                                                Log.e("tmessages", "drop frame startTime = " + startTime + " present time = " + info.presentationTimeUs);
                                            } else {
                                                videoTime = info.presentationTimeUs;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decoderStatus, doRender);
                                        if (doRender) {
                                            boolean errorWait = false;
                                            try {
                                                outputSurface.awaitNewImage();
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                errorWait = true;
                                                Log.e("tmessages", e.getMessage());
                                            }
                                            if (!errorWait) {
                                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
                                                    outputSurface.drawImage(false);
                                                    inputSurface.setPresentationTime(info.presentationTimeUs * 1000);
                                                    inputSurface.swapBuffers();
                                                } else {
                                                    int inputBufIndex = encoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
                                                    if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                                                        outputSurface.drawImage(true);
                                                        ByteBuffer rgbBuf = outputSurface.getFrame();
                                                        ByteBuffer yuvBuf = encoderInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];
                                                        yuvBuf.clear();
                                                        convertVideoFrame(rgbBuf, yuvBuf, colorFormat, resultWidth, resultHeight, padding, swapUV);
                                                        encoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, bufferSize, info.presentationTimeUs, 0);
                                                    } else {
                                                        Log.e("tmessages", "input buffer not available");
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                                            decoderOutputAvailable = false;
                                            Log.e("tmessages", "decoder stream end");
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
                                                encoder.signalEndOfInputStream();
                                            } else {
                                                int inputBufIndex = encoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
                                                if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                                                    encoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, 1, info.presentationTimeUs, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (videoTime != -1) {
                            videoStartTime = videoTime;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("tmessages", e.getMessage());
                        error = true;
                    }

                    extractor.unselectTrack(videoIndex);

                    if (outputSurface != null) {
                        outputSurface.release();
                    }
                    if (inputSurface != null) {
                        inputSurface.release();
                    }
                    if (decoder != null) {
                        decoder.stop();
                        decoder.release();
                    }
                    if (encoder != null) {
                        encoder.stop();
                        encoder.release();
                    }
                }


                if (!error) {
                    readAndWriteTrack(extractor, mediaMuxer, info, videoStartTime, endTime, cacheFile, true);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                error = true;
                Log.e("tmessages", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                if (extractor != null) {
                    extractor.release();
                }
                if (mediaMuxer != null) {
                    try {
                        mediaMuxer.finishMovie(false);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("tmessages", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                Log.e("tmessages", "time = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
            }
        } else {
            didWriteData(true, true);
            return false;
        }
        didWriteData(true, error);

        cachedFile = cacheFile;


        Log.e("ViratPath", path + "");
        Log.e("ViratPath", cacheFile.getPath() + "");
        if (sourcePath != null) {
            Log.e("SourcePath", sourcePath);
        }
        if (videoContentUri != null) {
            Log.e("VideoUri", videoContentUri.toString());
        }


        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Please try to show code samples as text formatted as code for clarity

Comment: var destinationfath="/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/"                                                                   var newpath= SiliCompressor.with(this).compressVideo(filepath,destinationfath).                  only this mych needes to compress video

Comment: If adding details or clarifying information for your Question please edit and add to Question, ensuring code and error samples are formatted as code. Do not add as a comment(s).

Comment: @moken plz check the image. i have uploded

Comment: @moken plz check the image. I have uploaded. I am doing simple video compression in Android kotlin by providing file path to SiliCompressor. Compression is working but it reduces the video size too much. my 14mb video compresses to 340kb.I want to do video compression without using FFMEG

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.